# What is the fastest way to verify that a json[] array is not empty?

Tags: postgresql, json, array

I want to verify that an `json[]` column `the_array` is not empty. For a *normal* array, I could check on:

```
the_array != '{}'
```

However, that does not work for a `json[]`, as demonstrated below:

```
select '{}'::json[] != '{}'
ERROR:  could not identify an equality operator for type json
```

I could use the following check instead:

```
array_length(the_array, 1) != null // yes, array_length on an
                                      empty array returns null
```

My fear is that `array_length()` would iterate over the whole array to count the number of items and then return that count. In my case, I don't need the actual size of the array, I just need to know whether it is empty or not.

So, does `array_length()` iterate over the whole array? And if so, is there a better way to check if a json array is empty?

Answer (score 21):

This is not returning a JSON Array,.

```
SELECT '{}'::json[]
```

The type `json[]` is not a "JSON Array", it's a SQL Array of type JSON. You should **never** be using this kind of structure. It's almost certainly a red flag of bad design.

What you want to check is that a Real JSON Array is not empty, you can do that with [`jsonb_array_length(jsonb)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html). JSON is stored as `JSON`, or `JSONB` for binary json.

```
SELECT jsonb_array_length( '[]'::jsonb );
```

To see if it's empty,

```
SELECT jsonb_array_length( '[]'::jsonb ) = 0;
```

Warning, this just counts those elements, **they may be null**,

```
SELECT jsonb_array_length( '[null]'::jsonb );
```

So you may want to call [`jsonb_strip_nulls()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html) on the array first.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, but I actually meant an SQL array of JSON documents, not a JSON array of JSON objects. So it is indeed a `json[]`. Consider something like `SELECT ARRAY(SELECT json_build_object('hello', 'world'))`.

Comment: You would just treat it like any other array if you want to know if it's empty just do `select thing = '{}'::json[];`, or test for `array_length(  '{}'::json[], 1 ) = 0`

Comment: @EvanCarroll `jsonb_strip_nulls()` does not remove `null` values from an jsonb array.